# How to call stored procedure with both of table value and scalar parametter in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to call a stored procedure that has two parameters:

- Id : `int`
- Data : `table user defined type`

I want to call this stored procedure using Entity Framework.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code:

```
public DataTable CallStoredProcedure(System.String procedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {
            var cmd = CreateStoredProcCallCommand(procedureName, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                var param = parameters.ElementAt(i);
                if (param.Value.GetType() == typeof(DataTable))
                    AddTableValuedParameter(cmd, "@" + param.Key, 0, ParameterDirection.Input, param.Value);
                else
                    AddParameter(cmd, "@" + param.Key, 2147483647, ParameterDirection.Input, param.Value);
            }

            var toReturn = new DataTable();
            CreateAndSetupAdapter(cmd).Fill(toReturn);
            return toReturn;
        }
private DbCommand CreateStoredProcCallCommand(string storedProcedureToCall, bool openConnection)
        {
            var cmd = _factoryToUse.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureToCall;
            return SetupCommand(cmd, openConnection);
        }
private DbDataAdapter CreateAndSetupAdapter(DbCommand selectCommand)
{
    var adapter = _factoryToUse.CreateDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
    return adapter;
}

 private static void AddTableValuedParameter(DbCommand cmd, string parameterName, int length, ParameterDirection direction, object value)
        {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = parameterName;
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            param.Size = length;
            param.Value = value;
            param.Direction = direction;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
private static void AddParameter(DbCommand cmd, string parameterName, int length, ParameterDirection direction, object value)
        {
            var dummyParam = new EntityParameter() { Value = value };
            var parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = parameterName;
            parameter.Direction = direction;
            parameter.Size = length;
            parameter.Value = value;
            parameter.DbType = dummyParam.DbType;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
```